# No names for skipped tests in codeception

Tags: php, codeception

In my functional tests (with Symfony3, Codeception 2.1.7 and PHPUnit 5.2.10) the skipped tests (invoked with `$scenario->skip`) are shown in the following way when I run `php vendor/bin/codecept run`:

`Example test (ExampleCest::test)                Skipped`

But at the end of the output, after time & memory statistics, the following additional output pops up:

```
There were 2 skipped tests:

---------
1) 
---------
2)
```

It seems unnecessary to show skipped tests again at this point, and even more senseless is the utter lack of information - no name or hint, even if I try to give the tests a name (`$I->wantTo`) or comment (`$scenario->comment`). Is there a way to improve the codeception output - remove the last paragraph, or at least add some useful information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in the master branch, so Codeception 2.2 will display skipped tests correctly. 
https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2654

You can get some useful information by running Codeception with -v or --debug parameters.

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure enough if this was a bug or if I just didn't know enough about Codeception yet.